# Update caption under grid

Tags: acumatica

Is there a code to update the yellow text?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the Grid details, (StatusField="Availability"), you can write field selecting event for Availability field and you can modify it.

SOLine_Availability_FieldSelecting event.

```
 <px:PXTabItem Text="Document Details">
<Template>
<px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Width="100%"
TabIndex="100" SkinID="DetailsInTab" StatusField="Availability" SyncPosition="True" Height="473px">
```